# How to prompt the receiver to display [title / subtitle / thumbnail] card on screen?

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm developing a custom receiver app using googlecast CAF SDK, in some cases I would like to display the metadata card on screen to reflecting the media information change, but it seems MEDIA_INFORMATION_CHANGED event would not automatically trigger this behavior.

I also tried the following:

1. Manually send local DISPLAY_STATUS request, but the console says it's no longer a valid parameter...
2. Use PlayerDataBinder to listen METADATA_CHANGED event then try to directly modify binded PlayerData object, but it seems not working at all...

Any kind of solution or suggestion is welcoming!

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.